# Approximation questions about $\ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Given $f(x) := \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}, \quad x \in ]-1,1]$

Find the second degree taylor polynomial at $x = 0$

Show that $\left|\ln \frac{1+x}{1-x} - 2x\right| \leq |x|^3$ for all $|x| < 10^{-1}$

Show that $\left|100 \int ^{\frac{1}{10}} _0 \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x} dx - 1\right| \leq \frac{10^{-2}}{4}$.

So I already found the taylor polynomial and got $(T_2f)(x) = 2x$

For the second one I got $|(R_3f)(x)| \leq 0.707686|x|^3$, at its highest value which satisifies the condition.

So for the last one I have a problem, approximating the function with $f(x) \approx 2x$ I get the antiderivative as $F(x) = x^2$, but I'm not sure how to use the error here to satisfy the condition. I tried substituting $x$ with $0.707686x^3$ but that doesnt help the slightest. I think I have misunderstood something here.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

I tried searching for similar problems but I was unable to find anything of help, I apologise if a question like this has been answered before!

EDIT: <strike>I think I figured it out by myself, would I be right in thinking that</strike>

$\left|100 \left(F(\frac{1}{10} \pm 0.7 \cdot 10^{-3}) - F(\pm 0.7 \cdot 10^{-3})\right) - 1\right| \leq \frac{10^{-2}}{4}$

Nevermind, it's wrong.

Comment: Note that $$1 = 100 \int_0^{\frac{1}{10}} 2x\,dx.$$

Comment: So, I take the integral

$\int ^{\frac{1}{10}} _0 2x \pm 0.707686x^3 dx$

With that I then get $|\pm 0.00177|$ which is less than $10^{-2}/4$

Comment: The idea is that you take $$\Biggl\lvert 100 \int_0^{\frac{1}{10}} \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}\,dx - 1\Biggr\rvert = \Biggl\lvert 100 \int_0^{\frac{1}{10}}\ln \frac{1+x}{1-x} - 2x\,dx\Biggr\rvert \leqslant 100 \int_0^{\frac{1}{10}} \biggl\lvert \ln \frac{1+x}{1-x} - 2x\biggr\rvert\,dx \leqslant 100 \int_0^{\frac{1}{10}} \lvert x\rvert^3\,dx.$$

Comment: Ah I see now, I misunderstood your first comment.